# что за функция move() в Image ? laravel

Tags: laravel

вот  здесь https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-8-resize-image-laravel-8-image-intervention-example

```
public function resizeImagePost(Request $request)

    {

        $this->validate($request, [

            'title' => 'required',

            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',

        ]);

  

        $image = $request->file('image');

        $input['imagename'] = time().'.'.$image->extension();

     

        $destinationPath = public_path('/thumbnail');

        $img = Image::make($image->path());

        $img->resize(100, 100, function ($constraint) {

            $constraint->aspectRatio();

        })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input['imagename']); //Здесь я понимаю сохраняется картинка

   
/*а здесь зачем это?
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');

        $image->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);
*/
   

        return back()

            ->with('success','Image Upload successful')

            ->with('imageName',$input['imagename']);

    }
```

Comment: move() переместить, $destinationPath путь назначения то есть директория в которую запишется изображение. Вначале записываете темп файл, делаете с ним какую то операцию и перемещаете его на статическое место

Comment: А по самоей логике кода, вы делаете вначале миниатюру и записываете её в соответствующую директорию, а потом сохраняете оригинал в директории с оригиналами

Comment: ок спасибо понял